# Null query in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the number of rows in a table with a particular column value = NULL in PostgreSQL. This is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM database.table 
WHERE place_id = 3 AND user = (NULL);
```

And I get the count as 0. But there a pretty number of rows matching the query. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `... and user is null`

Comment: worked! thank you @jarlh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use IS NULL:

```
Select count (*) from database.table where place_id = 3 and user IS NULL;
```

Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.) This behavior conforms to the SQL standard.

Comment: And the reverse is also true: `NULL` is neither _equal_  nor _not equal_ to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @Rogério Carvalho Batista

Answer (score 0):

If the value `NULL` comes from a variable, you can use `IS DISTINCT FROM` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` which can compare `NULL` values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from database.table
WHERE place_id = 3 and user IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL
```

This query will also work for other values, especially parameters. The query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from database.table
WHERE place_id = 3 and user IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $1
```

will work for `$1 = 'Tom'` and even `$1 = NULL`.